# Will Linux kernel automatically coalesce pages into 2M on x86_64?

Tags: linux, kernel, mmu

**The Background**

I've been digging through mainline for a few weeks now, trying to figure out how/if (and under what conditions) the kernel will automatically coalesce, say, 512 4k PTEs into a single 2M PMD entry - apart from pre-arranging this with hugetlbfs, or THP - so, purely by virtue of being x86_64.

I previously went along with the assumption that the TLB/MMU/Paging subsystem in-kernel will detect this and just do The Right Thing, but this doesn't seem to be the case, going by what I see in debugfs's kernel_page_tables when I run a test with a large .text section module (> 5MB).

**The Question(s)**

1) If the kernel really does automatically coalesce pages into a large page on the x86_64 architecture, then what conditions need to be set for this to happen?

2) If the kernel does not do this automatically, how does one manually take 512 4k PTEs, and coalesce them / convert them to be in the PMD?

I just need a hint; while i would've loved to have worked this all out on my own, it's been a few weeks now and am scratching my head with reckless abandon.

Many thanks

sc.

Comment: Does the MMU even have the capability to revise PTEs like that?  I highly doubt it.  More likely, the kernel page mapper logic might look for such opportunities when things are really fragmented, but it surely is a high cost and low benefit situation most of the time.

Comment: Thanks @wallyk - I updated the question to reflect your wise comments.

Comment: Yes, Linux uses anonymous / transparent hugepages opportunistically.  This http://developerblog.redhat.com/2014/03/10/examining-huge-pages-or-transparent-huge-pages-performance/.  See the other google hits for "anonhugepages".  That first google hit links to the in-kernel docs about it:  http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/andrea/aa.git/plain/Documentation/vm/transhuge.txt?id=HEAD.  The mainline version of this is https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/transhuge.txt

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna look at `khugepaged` daemon which does the splitting and merging of hugePages in Linux Kernel. But, this functionality is basically a support-system for THP.